# Is it bad practise to save string representations of Duration objects (and then eval()) in db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails application with some budget features...

What i want to do is allow users to create a `Budget` and specify a start date and an interval (like "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Yearly", etc). From that i wan't to build `BudgetPeriod`'s, the first one starting at the given start date and is "interval" long. The next period starts of where the previous ends and so it should continue as time goes...

A simple solution I came up with for this was to save the intervals as string representations of `Duration` objects, so Monthly would be "1.month" and Quarterly "3.months". And then use `eval(interval)` to calculate the periods start and end dates like this

```
after_create :create_periods
def create_periods
  period_start = self.starting_at
  while period_start <= Date.today
    next_start = period_start + eval(self.interval)
    period_end = next_start - 1.day
    budget_periods.create(start_date: period_start, end_date: period_end)
    period_start = next_start
  end
end
```

This works real good but I get a feeling that using eval() like that and basically save code in the database is not the right way to go.

So, is this bad practise or should i rock on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad! Try not to eval if you can possibly help it, it can be incredibly destructive if used improperly.

If you want to do this, it would be a better idea to dump what you're trying to store into the database and then get it out again later:

```
self.interval = Marshal.dump(3.months)

...

next_start = period_start + Marshal.load(self.interval)
```

If interval will always be dumped to and from the database like this, Rails offers a convenience method called serialize to do this automatically for you, so you'd only have to do this in your model:

```
serialize :interval
```

Then when you do `self.interval = 3.months` you're guaranteed to get just that Ruby object back out of your database, no eval necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But does this mean i can't have 1.month, 3.months,... as values in the form? like `f.select :interval, [['Monthly', '1.month'], ['Quarterly', '3.months'], ... ]`

Comment: I would definitely not do that, since it opens your form up to the possibility of having arbitrary data inserted into it and then read from your database. (Imagine if you were using eval() how awful it would be if someone posted "# `rm -rf /" into your database...) Instead, I would have the number directly (like '1' or '2') and in your model have a before_save that does something like ```interval = interval.to_i.months```.

Comment: Yeah it didn't feel right opening a door even with all kinds of validations and stuff. Thank you for the great answers, I'm gonna read up on Marshal and serialize. Maybe I'll find a way to preload a bunch of intervals.